# Generate dates Dates for PaymentInterest

Tags: sql, sql-server

### I need to generate grafic for PaymentInterest.

I have the date from wich i will generate graphic from '31/01/2012' to '31/01/2015'.  The next date for payment must be '28/02/2012','31/03/2012'.... until '31/01/2015'  the last date of the next month.
If the date will be '27/01/2012' the next date must be '27/02/2012','27/03/2012'.... until '31/01/2015' .

The problem is, i have the checkbox "Before Weekend" and if i check them and the next date is weekend i need to generate date before weekend if i uncheck "Before Weekend" and the next date it's weekend i need to generate date after weekend.

```
CCD.PercentDateFrom = '31/01/2012'
```

I have this my code but i don't like them and it's not work well

```
SELECT 
    PD.PercentRepaymentDate,
    PPP.MounthCount  --period 1 one month, 3 trimester, ..12 year and so on
FROM    CreditContracts CC
LEFT JOIN CreditContractDetails CCD 
    ON CCD.CreditContractID  = CC.id 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN DAY(DATEADD(DAY,1,CCD.PercentDateFrom)) = 1 --verify if the next day is the first day of month is mean the previous date is last date of month
             THEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MONTH, PPP.MounthCount * Number-1,CCD.PercentDateFrom))+1,0))
        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,number + PPP.MounthCount - 1,ISNULL(CCD.PercentDateFrom, CCD.ContractSignDate)) 
        END [PercentRepaymentDate]
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P'
        AND number <= CASE WHEN dbo.GetWorkDayByBranch(ISNULL(CCD.ContractExpireDate,dbo.GetMaxDateValue()),CC.BeforeWeekEnd,CCD.BranchID)<= '20120326' 
                            OR PPP.MounthCount = 0 
                            THEN 0 
                      ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH,CCD.PercentDateFrom,CCD.ContractExpireDate)/PPP.MounthCount 
                      END
        ) PD    
WHERE CC.CreditContract=1
```

My table of weekend is.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Weekends WHERE Date>='20120131'

Date    
2012-02-04 
2012-02-05
2012-02-11 
2012-02-12 
2012-02-18 
2012-02-19 
2012-02-25 
2012-02-26
2012-03-03 
2012-03-04 
2012-03-10 
2012-03-11 
2012-03-17 
2012-03-18 
2012-03-24 
2012-03-25 
2012-03-31 
2012-04-01 
2012-04-07 
2012-04-08 
2012-04-14 
2012-04-15 
.........
```

Sorry for my writer, it's my first post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just make a calendar table and use that?

Comment: It would help if you posted a specific question, and ideally a schema, sample data and expected output data. You can use sqlfiddle.com for this.

Comment: i think is a good idea to make a table and after that to use them, in just few moments i will make the input data and output  and how it must to look

Comment: this what i want to obtain http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/021c5/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this like that ))

--GetWorkDayByBranch(Date smalldatetime,BeforeWeekend int) this return the next  or previous work day
           --IF BeforeWeekend = 1 SET BeforeWeekend = -1 ELSE SET BeforeWeekend = 1 
           --DECLARE     @Result datetime
           --SET @Result = @Date
           --WHILE dbo.CheckWeekEndDayByBranch(@Result)=1 --check day from table, if exist we increment or decrement date depends of BeforeWeekend
           --BEGIN
           --SET @Result = DATEADD(day, BeforeWeekend, @Result)
           --END
           --RETURN @Result

```
       --@Period Period can be 1-month ,3 - trimester ,6 -semester , 12 - year

       SELECT dbo.GetWorkDayByBranch(CASE dbo.fnIsEdnOfMonth(@DateFrom)
                                            WHEN 1 THEN CASE  
                                                            WHEN dbo.EndOfMonth(DATEADD(MONTH,@Period * number,@DateFrom)) > @DateTo
                                                            THEN @DateTo
                                                            ELSE dbo.EndOfMonth(DATEADD(MONTH,@Period * number,@DateFrom))
                                                        END 

                                            ELSE 
                                                        CASE  
                                                            WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,@Period * number,@DateFrom) > @DateTo
                                                            THEN @DateTo
                                                            ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,@Period*number , @DateFrom)
                                                        END
                                   END
                ,@BeforeWeekends,1) ,
                @BeforeWeekends
            FROM MASTER..spt_values 
            WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH,@DateFrom,@DateTo) / @Period
```